# Python CGI Webform won't show link after Submit

Tags: python, hyperlink, webforms, cgi

I'm attempting a simple python CGI webform and I would like to display a list of links after the user presses the Submit button. I have found a lot of similar questions, but they were mostly about redirects. I am running this under Apache cgi-bin:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import psycopg2

cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

form=cgi.FieldStorage()


 if "site_id" not in form:
   print "<h1>The text input box was empty.</h1>"
 else:
   text=form["site_id"].value
   VAR_SITE_ID=cgi.escape(text)

(Some code here to insert variables into a database)

print "<a href="http://www.foo.com/">Visit Foo!</a>"
```

This works fine without the href line, however, when I include the href link, the webserver errors out with this in error_log:

```
"Premature end of script headers: textinput.py, referer:http://myipaddress
```

Why can't I print out a link to the browser?

Thanks!